# single item is showing in recycler view even though the entire screen is empty error?

Tags: android-recyclerview

Even though the entire screen is empty only one element is visible in recycle(r) view list. I have used wrap_content for height but still it is showing single element.But when I scroll that single element second element comes in first's place.Why is it happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the item layout of recyclerview,the height of your item maybe is match_parent.It's different from the listview item.